# Changing route without changing url in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I changed my route without changing url using skipLocationChange attribute like below.

```
          <a [routerLink]="['/articledetail']" skipLocationChange><h4>
                    {{article.HeadLine}}</h4></a>
```

But it goes to previous route while I am refreshing the page.It should be in latest route.How can I do that.pls help me.

Answer (score 8):

Browser does not know anything about the Angular routing. `skipLocationChange` does what it says - it does not register a state change anywhere, not in the browser history either. If you go to `'/b'` from `'/a'` skipping the location change, browser still thinks you are on `'/a'`. But you can try the following:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private location: Location, private router: Router) {}
...
// handle navigation not  by routerLink, but manually inside your component:
public navigate(): void {
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/articledetail', {skipLocationChange: true});
   this.location.replaceState('/articledetail');

}
```

And in your html:

```
<a (click)="navigate()">Your title</a>
```

But I don't clearly see the point of this, because `skipLocationChange`'s purpose is to actually trick the browser into thinking that no state change has occurred.

Comment: Oh. sorry, I actually even know a usage for this technique, as i used it in my current project: you can have tabs with different content in your page, and have a url assigned to each of this tabs, and use this to have a clean history (only the last tab's url will be stored in the browser's history, as you use `replaceState`, but when the user clicks on the browser's back button it won't navigate to previous tabs, but rather the previous page). And yes, this should actually solve your problem

Comment: thanks.but its not working as i am expected.my route is changed before navigation itself.After clicking on anchor tag it should goes to next route and should not change url

Comment: So wait, do you want to:
1. navigate from '/a' to '/b'
2. But the browser will still display '/a'
3. On refresh you want '/b to be shown?'

Comment: I need to navigate from a to b.but url should be a.on refereshing page content sholud be of b.

Comment: You see, this is even theoretically impossible. You app is destroyed, the only 'state' which is left is your url, which points to '/a', which will be loaded after refresh

Comment: But I don't really see why you would even need this kind of functionality

Comment: i need to change content without changing url

Comment: Then maybe you should seek some other approach like using `ngIf` on some content or so. You cannot solve this using routes

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't. When refreshing the page, the current state of your application is destroyed. The only "thing" that has a state is your url. Since you skip the location change it returns to the previous page.

Comment: That's not completely true, see my answer for a possible solution.